# Store HTML code in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am copying the "view source" of an external html page (1.html) into a variable in javascript in another html page (2.html). But due to the indentation, quotes, spaces and tags in the html page, i am not able to store all of the source code in the string at one go. Is there any function which can be used to do so?

Contents of 1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>1 </title>
</head>
<body>
    This is just plain text body
    <div id="new"> This id div text</div>
    <span> This is span text </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of 2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var str="<html>
<head>
    <title>2 </title>
</head>
<body>
    This is just plain text body
    <div id="new"> This id div text</div>
    <span> This is span text </span>
</body>
</html>";

alert (str);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

if a paste all the contents copied from 1.html after var=" inside 2.html, it does not take all of it.. Any solution to this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: to compare against changes, in html

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store multiline text in javascript string. To store that html in javascript you have to escape quotes and remove whitespace. Some examples:

**This won't work**:

```
var str = "Multiline
Text";
```

**This won't work either**:

```
var str = "Non-escaped text with "double quotes" and 'single quotes'";
```

**This will work**:

```
var str = "This will work because the \"double quotes\" are escaped";
```

Comment: yes.. i understand that.. I want to know is there any way of adding slashes and removing \n can be done automatically? any function? if yes, how to use it?

Comment: @user1196522: Which context are you talking about? Do you want to do this programmatically in JavaScript? If yes, how do you have access to `1.html`? Otherwise, use your favourite text editor and do a search/replace.

Comment: If you copy the source from browser and paste it directly to JS script, it won't work. Because the javascript engine will not be able to parse the code correctly and it won't run at all. If you're asking how to "fix" the source before pasting, that is way beyond the scope of your question and can be done in numerous ways.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes.. thats what i have been doing- using the text editor's find and replace.. and deleting the new lines.. but its very tedious, so wanted to know if there is something which can ease the task..

Comment: @package: yes.. thats exactly what i want to know. How to "fix" the source before pasting. i found some functions to addslashes to the code, but for that also i will need to have an acceptable (not multiline with proper quotes) string right?

Comment: When you ask for a 'function' you have to define context. A function of text editor, function of Javascript etc. Javascript is not suitable for this. I'd use some serverside programming language like php to output the javascript-friendly html string. On the other hand, there might be options working with text editors (macros, plugins, ect) but again, that is very broad question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape quote :

```
    <div id=\"new\"> This id div text</div>
```

And replace new line with `\n`